# Styled Components support for Preact without Preact Compat?

Tags: javascript, styled-components, preact

I've made a boilerplate project with Electron including Preact & Styled Components which can be found https://github.com/deadcoder0904/wip-desktop

It still throws error stating **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react'**

## webpack.config.js

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: "./src/react.js"
    }
  }
```

## src/react.js

```
module.exports = require("preact");

module.exports.PropTypes = { func() {} };
```

And I think I'm doing it right as mentioned in https://twitter.com/_developit/status/843536715587502080

Comment: In your tweet it says `.PropTypes = { func: {} };` but your `PropTypes` are `{ func() {} }`

Comment: still doesn't work or solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

React should be written with an uppercase `R`, that's likely the reason for the error.

As for the `PropTypes`, he since tweeted an updated solution using `babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types`: https://twitter.com/_developit/status/972933585538830336